# Managing split tees in golf

Tags: golf

This week at golf's [US Open](http://www.usopen.com/en_US/index.html), groups are teeing off the 1st and 9th holes. This is because the 9th tee is closer to the clubhouse than the 10th tee (i.e. logistics).

Split tees usually have groups tee off the 1st and 10th holes. However, wouldn't this kind of arrangement introduce more bottlenecks (assuming the same number of players tee off per group - eliminating the "uneven group" variable)? For example, one group gets held up. This holds the other groups back, eventually affecting groups who teed off the other hole to be affected.

How do golf organizers deal with split tee times and its risks, as it seems to introduce more unpredictable variables than traditional tee times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who don't know, with the majors, and a lot of other golf tournaments on the PGA and European tours, the first-two rounds have groups of three players and the groups tee off at 11 minute intervals.  In the 3rd and 4th rounds players play in pairs and at 10 minute intervals.  This can change subject to weather conditions, reduced daylight times, etc.

Now, these tee-times are extremely tightly regimented. For example, at the British Open, [Ivor Robson](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/sport/golf/theopen/8641600/The-Open-2011-How-Ivor-Robson-tones-up-his-silky-voice-for-simplest-job-on-course.html) can penalise a player 2 strokes if they are 2 minutes late and disqualify them if they are 5 minutes late.  That's certainly an incentive to be on time.

I'm not exactly sure as to when 11 minutes was set as the de facto for tee-time intervals, but it is one that the golf associations deem the optimum time to get every player out on the course.

Also, with an average round of golf taking a little over 4 hours, the tee-times are arranged so that, once the last groups have started, the 1st tee starters and the 10th tee starters should be nicely "in sync" on the whole course.

However, to prevent bottlenecks the following is done:

- [Slow play is penalised](http://www.independent.co.uk/sport/golf/kevin-garside-fishers-slowplay-penalty-should-give-dawdlers-a-hurryup-7815095.html) with a stroke penalty.
- In large fields, the round is [split into two halves](http://espn.go.com/golf/usopen12/story/_/id/7969359/tee-times-2012-us-open), with a morning group and an afternoon group.

Altogether, the 11 minute intervals, the size of the groups, the encouragement of quicker play and the splitting of the rounds, are what the associations believe to be the best way of preventing bottlenecks occurring.

That said, players do sometimes catch the group before them.  Only yesterday, on the first day of the 2012 US Open, Woods, Mickelson and Watson [had to wait over 15 minutes for the 7th green to clear](http://content.usatoday.com/communities/gameon/post/2012/06/live-blog-first-round-of-the-us-open-tiger-woods-bubba-watson/1#.T9sFg7Vn33U). (Live blog, 15:27).

In summary, the golf associations use their best judgement based on historical evidence whilst encouraging quick play.

Comment: Great answer! These are pro golfers so I don't expect much unprofessionalism taking place. As you said, players and golf associations prepare the best they can to prevent potential risks. Things still happen, but one can control only what s/he can control.

Comment: Waggle...waggle...(10 minutes later)...waggle. Just hit the ball!